# how to parse the json array unnamed json object in android?

Tags: android, json

my json code is mentioned below...

{ "CountryMobileCode": [     "+7 840",     "+93",     "+355",     "+1 684",     "+376",     "+244",     "+1 264",     "+1 268",     "+54",     "+374",     "+297",     "+247",     "+61",     "+672",     "+43",     "+994",     "+1 242",     "+973",     "+880",     "+1 246",     "+375",     "+32",     "+501",     "+229",     "+1 441",     "+975",     "+591",     "+387",     "+267",     "+55",     "+246",     "+1 284",     "+673",     "+359",     "+226",     "+257",     "+855",     "+237",     "+1",     "+238",     "+ 345",     "+236",     "+235",     "+56",     "+86",     "+57",     "+269",     "+242",     "+243",     "+682",     "+506",     "+385",     "+53",     "+599",     "+537",     "+420",     "+45",     "+253",     "+1 767",     "+1 809",     "+670",     "+593",     "+20",     "+503"   ]}

Anybody knows this Solution please write your answer... This is important in my project..

Comment: Did you want to parse it to `String` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Here jsonString is the json code you have mentioned in your question:

```
JSONObject object1=new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray arr=object1.getJSONArray("CountryMobileCode");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
System.out.println(arr.getString(i));
}
```

Comment: for more reference on json objects and arrays check out following link: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you very much Aakash.. Successfully Done.

Answer (score 2):

It's an Array of Strings... you can get the strings with the "for" statement and get values with the index position.

```
JSONArray json_code = json_response.getJSONArray("CountryMobileCode");

for (int i = 0; i < json_code.length(); i++) {

       Log.i("first", json_code.getString(0));
       Log.i("second", json_code.getString(1));
       // and so on...

}
```

Comment: what is use of making hard coded index in for loop ?